# Central Publication Repository

Tags: publications

I was wondering if there is a  central or an updated repository of various university publications (like ieee, but a bit more updated). I am using a university network, and I should have access to most of them.

Thanks

Comment: "University publications"? You don't mean press releases, newsletters, etc., published by a university, or do you?

Comment: No I meant papers released by PHD students or Proffessors

Comment: Do you need it for every possible field of research or just a specific field? For the latter it would be helpful to know the field.

Comment: Computer Science/Engineering but any other field would be nice too

Comment: Google Scholar is about as close as you're gonna get.

Comment: Meaning waht exactly?

Comment: Meaning, "No, not really."  Consult your librarian for details.

Answer (score 2):

Not Quite an Outsider has given the definitive answer in a comment. But answers belong as answers, not as comments, so I'll reproduce it here:

> "No, not really." Consult your librarian for details.

There is no single definitive store. There are several authoritative stores, and then a few that are broader but contain a lot of junk too, like Google Scholar. Part of being a post-graduate researcher is acquiring (if you haven't already), these skills & knowledge of the whens, wheres, whats, whys, and hows of search.

Work with your supervisors and fellow students to develop your own search skills.

**And talk to your librarians**. Seriously.